# Dbeaver - run all query without selecting it (CTEs)

Tags: dbeaver

Is it possible to run the whole SQL query with all CTEs without selecting the code?

eg:
with CTE1 as (..),
CTE2 as (..),
..
CTE30 as (..),
select * from CTE30;

What I want is to have the cursor at last line and ctrl+enter and runs the code without me selecting it. (In datagrip its possible. )